# Constraints within storyboard ViewController's root view don't apply with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uistoryboard

**It appears as though when you
`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` it doesn't apply any  constraints for UIView instances on the storyboard design surface but does for other objects like UILabel's. Is this really the rule?**

*Read on for full example.*

I can just add the constraints back in and everything is great. I can also use a ContainerView and embed the target ViewController in and it works just fine. I'm just trying to understand the limitations. It's only when I do this in code that I see this behavior.

Here's my setup starting with the storyboard:

[image: Storyboard Setup]

So I have an empty initial view controller and I have a "NextViewController" with 1 UIView. Taking a closer look there:

I have the background color on the NextViewController's root view set to a lime green:

[image: Lime Green Background]

And the design time added UIView (outlet to contentView) to that lighter blue. Additionally, I have constraints set on that lighter blue/contentView view:

[image: Consatraints]

Fill whatever view you are in, as I understand those constraints.

Now for the code in my "View Controller" that initializes the "Next View Controller":

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var next = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NextViewController")! as NextViewController

    println(next.view.constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis(.Vertical))
    println(next.view.constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis(.Horizontal))
    println(next.contentView.constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis(.Vertical))
    println(next.contentView.constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis(.Horizontal))

    view.addSubview(next.view)
}
```

That code gives me this output with the following logging:

[image: Output 1]

Note that the `constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis` all come back as empty for both `next.view` view and `next.contentView`. Also note that we see that lime green color filling the screen, but we don't see the light blue.

Additionally the values for these lines helps to potentially explain things:

```
// true
println(next.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints())

// false
println(next.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints())
```

I can fix this, and make the light blue content view show if I apply the following constraints:

```
var names = ["contentView": next.contentView]

var h1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[contentView]|",
    options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: names)

var v1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[contentView]|",
    options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: names)

view.addConstraints(h1 + v1)
```

[image: Output 2]

I can achieve the same rendered output if I do the following in the "View Controller" as well. I omit all the loading code above and use a storyboard Container View:

[image: View Controller With Container]

The following constraints are applied to the container:

[image: Consatraints]

So it appears as though `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` is clearly doing something or not doing something that the container view in the storyboard is doing/not doing.

Another test I ran adds a label with center X/Y constraints as a sibling of the light blue container:

[image: Sibling Label]

That renders as follows:

[image: Centered Label Output]

The constraints on the UILabel are left intact but the contentView's constraints are not present! The code to load this example:

```
var next = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NextViewController")! as NextViewController
view.addSubview(next.view)
```

And just to see what the translatesAutoResizingMask is on the UILabel:

```
// true
println(next.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints())

// false
println(next.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints())

// false
println(next.myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints())
```

I also tried adding additional UIView's to the design surface in the storyboard, and setting their constraints to occupy the full view. My thinking was maybe it only kills the constraints on the 1st UIView it encounters. The short answer is no, All UIView's are affected if their constraints are told to go edge-to-edge.

I also added a UIView that didn't go edge-to-edge. It's constraints were retained.

So that leaves me with asking, what's going on here? Should I always be taking into account UIViews in ViewControllers I load though `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` if their constraints are edge-to-edge?

Comment: What solution did you adopt in the end?

Comment: It's been a while, I honestly forget what I ended up doing.